# can't figure addEventListener error when script is in body

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a submit button using an `addEventListner` to a form, but I am stuck with the `addEventlister` of undefined error.  I tested if the element is `true` and it returns `true`.

This is my form:

```
<form action="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text" autocomplete="given-name">
    <input name="lastname" type="text" autocomplete="given-name">
    <button type="button" id="for_input">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This my java script:

```
//Check if the element exists.
var el = document.getElementsByName('for_input');
        if(el) //check if true
            console.log("Value is true"); 
        else
            console.log("Value is false");

//define alert to check click        
var showMe = function(){alert("clicked worked");}; 


el[0].addEventListener("click", showMe,false);
```

The error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of
>   undefined

I tried adding to the of the html body but still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any element name of `for_input`, but you have a **button** with an **ID** of `for_input`. So use `querySelector` or `getElementById` method instead of `getElementsByName` method on `document`.

```
var el = document.querySelector('#for_input');
if (el) //check if true
  console.log("Value is true");
else
  console.log("Value is false");

//define alert to check click        
var showMe = function () { alert("clicked worked"); };


el.addEventListener("click", showMe, false);
```

`document.getElementsByName('for_input')` returns `NodeList []`, which was assigned to `el`, as there is no html element of `name="for_input"` found in the `document` object. Later when you called `el[0]` it gave you `undefined` because `el` has an empty node list. So `undefined.addEventListener(..)` call caused the error you see in the log.

Comment: thanks work like a charm. I have been stuck for 1 and half hrs on that.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the name, you are using id="for_input" instead of name="for_input".

```
<button type="button" name="for_input">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing element with name `for_input`, its button id, So use `getElementById`

```
var el = document.getElementById('for_input');
```

Now `el` is not an array, so no need to add array position like `el[0]` just use `el`

```
el.addEventListener("click", showMe, false);
```